# php number compare Array

Tags: php, arrays

i have student for examiner Language Level 
For Example:
  (8,8,9,8,7) Repeat number "8" Get "8" 
  (7,7,8,9,10) Repeat Number "7" Get "7" 
  (7,8,9,10,9) no Repeat number Get Last "9"
  (7,7,8,8,9) forget "7" > Get Last Repeat number "8"
  (7,7,8,9,9) forget "7" >Get Last Repeat number "9"

CODE here

//get duplicate
    function getArrayDups($array)
    {
      $counts = array_count_values($array);
        return array_filter(
      $counts,
      create_function(
         '$val',
         'return($val > 1);'
         )
       );
    }

```
// usage test:
$test = array('8','8','7','7','7');
$result = getArrayDups($test);
    if(count($result))
    {
      echo "<p>You had one or more duplicate entries:</p>\n<ul>\n";
    foreach($result as $entry => $count)
     {
   if ($count >= 3){
     echo "<li> Get Level is  $entry ($count)</li>";
   break;  
   } 
 echo "<li>  Level is $entry ($count)</li>"; 
}
 }
  else
  {
  //echo end($test);
  echo "<li>No duplicates  Level found. last Level." . end($test) . "</li>";
  }
```

I was wondering if anyone had any other ideas about how I might achieve this.

Comment: See [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Comment: Your `$str[$i]` will fail on `10`. It also receives commas as numbers.  You need to `explode` it first.

Comment: this code i'll rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `(8,8,9,8,7)` is a string you can convert it into array using `explode` and the use `array_count_values`, if your data is already an array (like `$arr = [8,8,9,8,7]`) you could directly use `array_count_values`

So you'd be doing something like:

```
<?php
    $str = '8,8,9,8,7';
    $arr = explode(',', $str);
    $arrCount = array_count_values($arr);
    $temp= false;
    for($i=count($arr)-1;$i> 0;$i--) {
        if($arrCount[$arr[$i]] > 1) {
           echo "last repeat is: ".$arr[$i];
           $temp = true;
           break;
        }
    }
    if(!$temp)
        echo "no repeat found";

?>
```

Comment: my date from sql query, like this :SELECT set1,set2,set3,set4,set5 FROM level where test_id = '$test_id"  , set1 set2 ..... = 8, 8, 9, 8, 7